# Random images with specific click events in android

Tags: android

```
final ImageView imageview_array[] = {Tapimage1, Tapimage2, Tapimage3, Tapimage4, Tapimage5, Tapimage6, Tapimage7, Tapimage8, Tapimage9, Tapimage10, Tapimage11, Tapimage12, Tapimage13, Tapimage14, Tapimage15};


    final int[] images = {R.drawable.circle_01, R.drawable.square_01, R.drawable.triangle_01,
            R.drawable.circle_02, R.drawable.square_02, R.drawable.triangle_02,
            R.drawable.circle_03, R.drawable.square_03, R.drawable.triangle_03,
            R.drawable.circle_04, R.drawable.square_04, R.drawable.triangle_04,
            R.drawable.circle_05, R.drawable.square_05, R.drawable.triangle_05};
    final int[] image_id = {R.id.tap_cir_image1, R.id.tap_cir_image2, R.id.tap_cir_image3,
            R.id.tap_cir_image4, R.id.tap_cir_image5, R.id.tap_cir_image6,
            R.id.tap_cir_image7, R.id.tap_cir_image8, R.id.tap_cir_image9,
            R.id.tap_cir_image10, R.id.tap_cir_image11, R.id.tap_cir_image12,
            R.id.tap_cir_image13, R.id.tap_cir_image14, R.id.tap_cir_image15};



    final int[] circles_array = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};

    int[] image_index = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};

    List<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        dataList.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(dataList);
    shuffle_array = new int[dataList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        shuffle_array[i] = dataList.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < shuffle_array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(shuffle_array[i]);
    }
    Log.e(" shuffle array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(shuffle_array));





    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height, width);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = rightMargin;
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    for (i = 0; i < shuffle_array.length; i++) {
        temp = shuffle_array[i];
        imageview_array[i].setBackgroundResource(images[temp]);
        imageview_array[i].setId(i);

        Log.e("temp", "" + temp);

        imageview_array[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(circles_array[temp] == 1 )
                {
                    imageview_array[temp].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    count++;
                }



}
```

I have 15 images and 3 linear layouts. I want to arrange 5 images in each layout which randomly generate every time a user visits that page.

How do I set ids for random images and with corresponding click events?

For example I have 15 images
              ---> 5(circles)
              ---> 5(triangles)
              ---> 5(squares)
All these are randomly arranged in 3 layouts and I want to click circles only.

[Picture of what I want]

[image]

Comment: where is the code ???

Answer (score 0):

this is somewhat vague but if I'm guessing your goal right, you should assign your views ids and instead randomize their drawables,

```
//pseudocode because I have no idea how you want to do this
class MyPacket{
//local class,lazy way of packaging all your views with an appropriate listener
int id;//drawable id

//pass in all your ids of a certain type with whatever listener type you want
View.onClickListener listener

}
//change your int[] to some MyPacket collection, then for each of your views

ImageView somename= (ImageView) findViewbyId(someID);
somename.setDrawable(mPacketCollection.getFirst().id));
somename.setOnClickListener(mPacketCollection.getFirst().listener);
mPacketCollection.remove(0);
//repeat for each view
```

This is a poor example but hopefully it helps. There's no real point in randomizing the views themselves when you don't actually care about them.